Updating classic website with Next js on Plesk
My task is to update old website with new. My client use VPS with Plesk and his old website is written on html, css and js. So I have created the updated version of it using Next Js. Then I created temporary free domain and deployed Next app, so everything is working fine. Now I need to run this next app under primary domain name.
So I tried simply switch domains between these two projects, but this didn't work. I tried to switch old website root folder to next js root folder - this also didn't work. Then I tried to add node js to the old website project, filled document root, application root and application startup file data with data from my working next js project, runned build and start commands, but recieved:
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
For deploying I have used this tutorial:
https://kdaws.com/learn/building-and-running-next-js-apps-on-plesk/
Please, give me suggestion, how to safely run next app on primary domain.

please provide logs and non sensitive details about server setup

Your problem is that there is another process running on that system that listens on port 3000.  The error message clearly says that: "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000"
Either find out which process that is and stop it or change the port that your next.js server is listening on.
Finding out Which Process Listens on Port 3000
On Linux or MacOS run lsof -i :3000. On Windows the command netstat -aon | findstr :3000 should work.
Changing the Next.js Port
Open package.json in your project directory and change the commands dev and start in the scripts section:
"scripts": {
    ...
    "dev": "next dev -p 3001",
    "start": "next start -p 3001",
    ...
}

Replace 3001 with a port of your choice that is not in use on your system.
